# Deleting multiple entities at once in C# winForm

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using the following code to delete records from entity model by datagridview in a winForm application.

```
var context= new AdminEntites();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvLoadTable.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["chkcol"].Value != null && row.Cells["chkcol"].Value.Equals(true)) 
        {

            var selectedRec = (FILTER)this.rtBindingSource.Current;
                     //FILTER is the table name
                 context.DeleteObject(selectedRec);
                 context.SaveChanges();
          }
      }
```

This code is only deleting a single row one at a time. How can I delete all the selected rows at once?

Comment: did that, doesn't work.

Comment: I'm new to C# but it looks like your calling `rtBindingSource.Current` Doesn't that mean the last selected record??

Comment: Yes, it does, that's why I'm calling it inside foreach loop. Anyways, I got another solution, so the problem is solved. Thanks all of you for help.

Comment: Can you please show us how you solved it? It might help others with the same problem as this.

Comment: @bodjo YES YES YES. Save the NEWBS (Like Me. :-) )

Comment: I have added the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code is:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvLoadTable.SelectedRows)
 {
    if (row.Cells["chkcol"].Value != null && row.Cells["chkcol"].Value.Equals(true)) 
    rtBindingSource.RemoveAt(row.Index);
  }//end of foreach
context.SaveChanges();
```